# IIS service status / Error calling OpenSCManager()[code:5]

Tags: iis, web-server

Okay I'm totally new here so give me a chance here. Not much of a server person here.

I'm trying to setup a Web Server here. 
I get the error on the installer

"Error calling OpenSCManager()[code:5] while querying service "W3SVC" status.

then

"Cannot get IIS service status, make sure IIS have been installed."

I have installed IIS as I can see it under the system admin tools.

I'm Windows 7 Pro. Can you point me in the right direction?

- **Do I just need a better understanding of IIS? If so recommend some good tutorial web-sites?**
- **Or is this a specific enough that someone can answer this question to some degree?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your details here, but my checklist for what you've given me here is:

1. Make sure you are *really* an administrator equivalent when running the setup for IIS.
2. Do you get any errors when you run inetmgr? Start, Run, inetmgr [Enter]
3. Do you have the default C:\inetpub\wwwroot directory created?
4. What do you see if you run iisreset from an Administrator's Command Prompt?